# Get All Revisions for a specific file in gitpython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am using [gitpython](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GitPython/) library for performing git operations, retrieve git info from python code. I want to retrieve all revisions for a specific file. But couldn't find a specific reference for this on the [docs](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org).

Can anybody give some clue on which function will help in this regard? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so, as the referred-to question doesn't involve gitpython at all.

Answer (score 9):

A follow-on, to read each file:

```
import git
repo = git.Repo()
path = "file_you_are_looking_for"

revlist = (
    (commit, (commit.tree / path).data_stream.read())
    for commit in repo.iter_commits(paths=path)
)

for commit, filecontents in revlist:
    ...
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no such function, but it is easily implemented:

```
import git
repo = git.Repo()
path = "dir/file_you_are_looking_for"

commits_touching_path = list(repo.iter_commits(paths=path))
```

Performance will be moderate even if multiple paths are involved. Benchmarks and more code about that [can be found in an issue on github](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/240).